# Inequivalent unitary representations of a compact group must be orthogonal

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a compact group, and let $\mathcal{H}$ be a unitary representation. I have come across the claim that if $\mathcal{H}_0$ and $\mathcal{H}_1$ are two irreducible subrepresentations which are not unitarily equivalent, then they must be orthogonal. I would like to understand why. I can show that if they are not orthogonal, then the orthogonal projection of one to the other is a linear equivalence, but I am struggling to show that this map will be equivalent to a unitary. Am I missing some clever averaging trick?

Comment: I think this follows from Schur's lemma.

Comment: Hi Qidi...as far as I can tell, Schur's lemma gives the linear equivalence, but I want unitary equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\pi_i:G\to\mathcal{H}_i$ be the two unitary representations and $A\colon \mathcal{H}_0 \to \mathcal{H}_1$ be the linear equivalence you have, i.e. $A\pi_0A^{-1} = \pi_1$, then
$$
\pi_1^{-1} = \pi_1^{*} = (A\pi_0A^{-1})^* = A^{*-1}\pi_0^{*}A^* = A^{*-1}\pi_0^{-1}A^* \Rightarrow A^*\pi_0A^{*-1} = \pi_1
$$
Therefore $A^*$ is also a linear equivalence, and consequently $\sqrt{A^*A}$ is a linear equivalence.

The polar decomposition of $A$ gives $A = U\sqrt{A^*A}$ where $U$ is unitary, so $U = A\sqrt{A^*A}^{-1}$ is the unitary equivalence we are looking for.